# How to access a decorated jsp pages from with another decorated jsp view

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, decorator

its some how difficult to explain it in simple words . But , I will try as much as possible.

Here is the thing :

I have jsp page `FAQ` in `Spring MVC` that uses a decorator called `decorator.static.jsp` 
when ever a request comes to `/myapp/static/**` ,ok?

Then , after for a page after login I use a decorator like `/myapp/secured/**` then apply 
`decorator.secured.jsp`

The problem is I have a menu on the bottom of the app like

> FAQ | AboutUs | Home

and when i click on FAQ the app goes to

> secure/home

instead

> /myapp/static/faq/controller

How can I access static pages with like FAQ after I login.

Please , let me know if I have to explain more , Thank you Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Put the top menu in a different html file say menu.html

Now include this html page on your JSP page as :

```
<%@include file="menu.html" %>
```

Comment: that does;t help sorry